# Unable to test facebook feed webhook. Webhook not receiving events

Tags: facebook, webhooks

Following the recent changes for facebook developer, i had this alert on the webhook section on the developer dashboard, and therefore no webhook messages are received from 'testers, devs, etc' ;

Application will only be able to receive test webhooks sent from ...

[Facebook not allowing webhooks anymore in development mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjIeF.png)

As a result i am unable to test my mesenger bot apps. I am administrator of my Pages as well as I am administrator of my facebook application.

Whenever I add any comment or likes on my pages, I don't get any webhook event fired.

My pages have subscribed to my app.

The problem now is - My application is in development mode. I can't test it. And facebook won't approve it because they also are not able to test it as I have to mention steps.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Guess you are supposed to send test webhook calls from the app dashboard then to test your functionality.

Comment: @misorude test webhook does not have all the options. for example add comment or remove comment test webhooks are not there